# INDEX, COUNTA? Repeat row value N times for every nonblank cell in criteria

Tags: excel, indexing, match

**Questions**:

- I can't quite figure out the function needed in order to list each vegetable in a single column (in Table 2 Col C) the same number of times (weeks) it is harvested in Table 1 (col C-E)? Would I use Index with some other function?
- For each time a vegetable is repeated in a row in Table 2, how can I match each repetition to each of its harvest weeks (1 per row) in a neighboring column in Table 2? (See Table 2, Col D)

  TABLE 1

  ```
      A    B    C     D     E
    crop  unit  aug8  aug15 aug22
  1 corn  ear   10          
  2 onion lb    15            
  3 beets lb    5     5     5
  ```

TABLE 2

```
        A     B    C     D          
      date1 date2 crop  harvest date  
    1             corn  aug8
    2             onion aug8
    3             beets aug8
    4             beets aug15
    5             beets aug22
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I think this would be the easiest to achieve using the [pivot table wizard](http://superuser.com/questions/78439/is-it-possible-to-unpivot-or-reverse-pivot-in-excel). Any formulaic solution will be extremely brittle and complex.

Comment: Robin, I agree it is an awkward request. Your link is very interesting. I'll check out your pivot table link and see if I can't make it work for me some how. I'm just not sure how I could use a pivot table to include new columns as well as formulas to then compute additional dates as well as pull data from another table that will be used to compute these other dates.

Comment: Some of the formula's from Robin's link were interesting as was the pivot info, but I don't think it's quite the solution I'm looking for. The search continues.

Comment: found a formula that works based on names crops listed in A and quantity in Col E. Formula is in column G. G1 Array: =INDEX(A2:A16390,MATCH(TRUE,E2:E16390<>0,0)) G2 Array: =IFERROR(IF(COUNTIF($G$2:G2,G2)=INDEX(E:E,MATCH(G2,A:A,0)),IF(AND(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(G2,A:A,0)+1)<>0,INDEX(E:E,MATCH(G2,A:A,0)+1)<>0),INDEX(A:A,MATCH(G2,A:A,0)+1),"-"),G2),"-")